# Python: Using my Script with all dependencies on a different computer

Tags: python, import, package, egg

I want to run my Python script on a different computer.
This computer does not have all the dependencies i have imported in my script and I dont have admin privileges on it.

So i thought I create a package.("Gag" is my created package)
I created setupy.py.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='Gag',
      version='0.1',
      author='me',
      author_email='person@mail.com',
      packages=['Gag'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I installed it locally as a user on the computer with

```
pip install file:/home/students/olimue/GA/GAPackage/Gag/ --user
```

But it still didnt have all the dependencies and gave me an Importerror.

So how do I simply include all dependencies in my package as a whole?
That I just need to install the file and run it?

Comment: I dont see you listing the dependencies anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or any similar software, that will do the work for You.